# How to get sum of numbers in a column w.r.t corresponding dates in another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have mentioned in the image what i need. Please help me.
Thanks.

Got it . Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you try SuMIFS?

Comment: Also the question should have the information needed in the question and not on a photo.  Photos should be support for the verbiage, not the other way around.

Comment: create the list of unique dates with the `UNIQUE()` function and then use `SUMIF()` to calculate the conditional sums.

Comment: sorry. i thought image would be easier to get. 
As suggested by @DattelKlauber, i have sorted the dates using unique. Can you help with Sumif ?

Comment: @NoobMaster It looks like you already got the result you needed using the `=SUMIFS(C2:C1200,B2:B1200, E2:E1200)` formula, is that correct?

Comment: @FernandoLara Yes, i got the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution using UNIQUE() function and then use SUMIF(). Closed.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question please mark it as accepted - the check mark under the voting buttons on the left.